# How do I disconnect a garbage disposal from a junction box? What to do with loose wires?

Tags: junction-box

I just removed part of our cabinet during demo and our kitchen has a hardwired garbage disposal to a junction box on the wall. [image: disposal junction box]

I want to disconnect my disposal during demo and save it for reuse in our remodel.

How do I disconnect the disposal from the junction box and reconnect the loose wires in junction box so that the path of electricity is still maintained for the other parts of the kitchen?

I'm pretty sure I know how to disconnect it...
(1) Turn off power at the breaker box
(2) Open junction box and disconnect wires that goes to the disposal
(3) ...what do I do next with the loose wires?  (I guess I should open the box and take a picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you know most steps leading up to it. Based on that it seems you only want to know what to do with the wires once disposal wiring is removed.

I would simply take wiring caps and place one on each exposed wire and then wrap each wire with some electrical tape further ensuring the caps stay on and do not become exposed if touched or caught when working around the wires. If you are keeping the junction box I would still use the same method but place wires back in the box and and screw the plate back on. Pull wire to sit inside of junction box or just place the end in the box and screw plate back on.

[image: Screw on one wire cap/nut on each wire.]
Screw on one wire cap/nut on each wire.
[image: Tape each wire cap/nut separately]
Tape each wire cap/nut separately

Comment: This will ensure that the electricity still flows ok to the rest of the circuit?

Comment: Yes. In short a junction box is used as a splitter with one of the ends going to and ending at the garbage disposal. Just leave the other wires in the junction box as is. Basically it is equivalent to unplugging the garbage disposal from a wall and since there is no plug at the end, you are capping and taping it.

Comment: So I'm basically removing a load in a parallel circuit right?  Also I'm not suppose to use a wire nut on two wires connected together as you have shown in the picture lright?

Comment: Yes you are removing a load and yes it is parallel wiring, but since it is  at the end out of a junction box it really isnt parallel in a sense, meaning it wont break the current flow of anything else on the line which removing a load from parallel wiring would normally do, if not reconnected. Also, yes I would use wire caps (nut) and tape just to be safe..

Comment: NO! Do not connect any wires to each other. Once you remove the 3 wires for the disposal, can and tape them individually. That pic was just to show what wire caps/buts are, and how to tape them . :)