# Is there a technique to leave cabling in place for optional pod lights that you are not decided if you want or need?

Tags: electrical

I have a spot where I want but I don't know if I should put a pod light. It is right above the shower base, toward its 2/3rds point, opposite to the shower column. I am not sure if I need it right now but I would like to draw an cable to that point and leave it there and cut the opening and use it only if I realize I need it

Is this a valid answer for ceiling as well ?

[How do I disconnect a garbage disposal from a junction box? What to do with loose wires?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/98783/how-do-i-disconnect-a-garbage-disposal-from-a-junction-box-what-to-do-with-loos)

Comment: If placing cable/conduit for maybe future use, only thing I would do is maybe label it.  Nothing worst than some future owner finding a cable with no use.

Comment: the next owner will get all the documentation he or she ever could dream about including a 3D model (sketchup) of the house in the most intimate details of the building. That assuming there are no hostilities when I sell (like trying to speculate a bad market and trying to bring the price down )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install wire in advance. If you use conduit (required in some areas) then run the conduit to a junction box and put a cover on the box, *but no need to run wires*. If you don't use conduit, run a NM /2 or /3 cable into a junction box. Make sure there is plenty of excess on the cable (coil it up) to make installation easier). Cap each wire (except ground) with a wire nut.

**/2 vs. /3** Normally you only need /2 for a light. However, over a shower you (or a future owner) may want a combination light/fan, which will require a /3 cable. Might even want heat/light/fan, which would require a /4 cable, but that is less common. So I'd probably go for a /3 - the extra cost is minimal.

In any case, put the end inside a proper junction box with a cover. That cover must remain accessible. If the ceiling is white, a standard white cover will do just fine and will hardly be noticeable.

As far as the other end, I would run it to the switch box for the bathroom. If you haven't already installed that box, I would put in a relatively large/deep box so that you have plenty of space for installation of additional switches in the future.

Comment: fan is on a separate switch (its own wire). pod lights are chained so I just need to run a wire to the previous pod, it is all three wires anyway

Comment: Oops, I missed that this was with a previous "pod". Might actually still make sense to wire back to switch box - *you* think it would work best all on one switch. But you aren't even  installing that light, so wiring back tot he switch gives you the option of "same switch" or "separate switch".

Comment: must the junction box remain accessible even is the cable is not powered?

Comment: Technically no. But if you're going to do that, I would not bother running the cable at all.